# My list of objects does not render in lightning table after deserialization in Apex

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, json, lwc-wire-adapter

So I have this big JSON file that I'm trying to display in the table in LWC. I have made an Apex class that will deserialize my JSON file into Objects. My JSON file is uploaded in Static Resources.

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class JsonParserController {

public String value1;
public String value2;
public String value3;
public String value4;
public String value5;
public String value6;

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<JsonParserController> getJsonData() {

        StaticResource jsonData = [SELECT Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'jsonDataNetworks'];

        String jsonString = jsonData.Body.toString();
        List<JsonParserController> parsedData = (List<JsonParserController>) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonString, List<JsonParserController>.class); 
        System.debug(parsedData);
        return parsedData;
}
}
```

**System.debug(parsedData) from Apex class displays correct information.**

But when I try to wire and render this data in my LWC component I do not see any data, only columns that I defined. **It returns the correct number of Objects but the values are not there.**

This is my JS file:

```
import { LightningElement,wire } from 'lwc';
import getJsonData from '@salesforce/apex/JsonParserController.getJsonData'

const columns = [
  { label: 'value1', fieldName: 'value1' },
  { label: 'value2', fieldName: 'value2' },
  { label: 'value3', fieldName: 'value3' },
  { label: 'value4', fieldName: 'value4' },
  { label: 'value5', fieldName: 'value5',
    label: 'value6', fieldName: 'value6',
    label: 'Action', type:'button', typeAttributes:{
      label: 'Add',
      name:'Add',
      title: 'Add',
    }},
];
export default class JsonInLwc extends LightningElement {

  columns = columns;

  @wire(getJsonData)
  parsedDataFromApex;

}
```

And my html file:

```
<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={parsedDataFromApex.data}
                columns={columns}
                hide-checkbox-column="true"
                show-row-number-column="true">
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>
```

Here is a picture of what I see:

[image: display]

I have made sure that the values from my JSON file correspond to my column fieldNames. Also when I consol.log(data) it returns Object. But other than that I do not se the problem. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables need to be AuraEnabled and have a getter and setter so that they become properties:

```
@AuraEnabled public String value1 { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled public String value2 { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled public String value3 { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled public String value4 { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled public String value5 { get; set; }
@AuraEnabled public String value6 { get; set; }
```

This is a feature I'm building into the next version of json2Apex.